# In Flutter and if the number after decimal point is equal 0 convert the number to int

Tags: flutter

This is a function if the `endValueFixed` is equal for example 12.0 I want to print the number without zero so I want it to be 12.

```
  void calculateIncrease() {
    setState(() {
      primerResult = (startingValue * percentage) / 100;
      endValue = startingValue + primerResult;
      endValueFixe`enter code here`d = roundDouble(endValue, 2);
     
    });
  }
```

Comment: Check out this great article https://www.technicalfeeder.com/2021/12/dart-handling-the-length-after-decimal-point/

Answer (score 1):

This may be an overkill but it works exactly as you wish:

```
void main() {
  // This is your double value
  final end = 98.04;
  String intPart = "";
  String doublePart = "";
  int j = 0;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < end.toString().length; i++) {
      if (end.toString()[i] != '.') {
        intPart += end.toString()[i];
      } else {
        j = i + 1;
        break;
      }
  }
      for (int l = j; l < end.toString().length; l++) {
        doublePart += end.toString()[l];
  }
  if (doublePart[0] == "0" && doublePart[1] != "0") {
    print(end);
  } else {
    print(end.toString());
  }
  }
```

You may use this code as a function and send whatever value to end.

Comment: I change 'end' with 'endValueFixed'
and instead of print 'end', I want to save the value in 'endValueFixed'
but it doesn't work , it say  : A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'double'

Comment: when you want to assign the value, use : int.parse(value)

Comment: if you got your answer accept my answer to close the topic.

Comment: Brother, I have a note :
your answer above is good but there is a problem :
for example, if the number = 98.04 your code converts it to 98  I don't want that, I want it to show as it is, I only want the convert to take place if it is only after point is 0  like 98.0 

thanks, I am waiting for your answer

Comment: I have changed the code for you and it works as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot my brother

Comment: if it is as you wanted then accept my answer to close the topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (endValueFixed==12) {
  print('${endValueFixed.toInt()}');
}
```

conditionally cast it to an int and print it then :)

Comment: I want to convert any number, not just 12.0

Comment: @abdulla Did you understand the answer at all?

Comment: @abdullah you can also cast any other number to int then

Comment: I want to check the number if the number has zero after the point so I want to delete the zero 
, for example, the result equals 24.0 I want to print it 24 
If the result equal 24.3  no problem print it 24.3